# Java Guava Ratelimiter used by Swing Worker, slow execution

Tags: java, swing, guava

I have an app which is using swing workers in combination with guavas ratelimiter. I have set the ratelimiter to 18 permits per second but my data gets loaded way slower than this. Am I doing something wrong here, or do I understand the basics wrong (coming from nodejs)?

I thought the iteration that is making the API calls will execute 18 times per second using this code. But it seems like it is way slower, as if it is always waiting for one iteration to completely finish before executing the next. From my understanding, with the ratelimiter it should be 18 per second or at least, no more.

```
 @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
        tickers = rc.getAll24HrPriceStatistics();   

        progressBar.setMaximum(tickers.size());
        for(int i=0; i< tickers.size();i++){
            Market market = new Market(screener, tickers.get(i).getSymbol(),timeframe);
            rateLimiter.acquire();
            market.initializeCandles(); //this executes a 3rd party API call
            table.addMarket(market);
            publish(i);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

EDIT: When I leave out the ratelimiter it has no effect in speed of execution so my guess is, that these tasks are not executed in parallel but rather one after the other. This makes me question how to make the swingworker execute these concurrently by using the rate limiters permits per second.

Comment: Hard to debug without more context. How is the `rateLimiter` constructed? How are you testing it? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: What happens when you take out the rate limiter? Maybe whatever the things you are doing are, maybe they are the bottleneck?

Comment: when I take out the rate limiter the speed is the same. So I guess it is executing one after another in this loop. Is there any way to make the calls concurrent?

Comment: @BitQueen: that's a good finding, but please [edit] your question to reflect that. Others might come to this question and try to answer when the question as written is no longer relevant.

Comment: You're doing everything in one thread. Your expectation of speed is multithreaded. Make sure your code is multithreaded.

Comment: First of all, you should understand a fundamental thing about the SwingWorker: your implementation is supposed to `publish` the *results*, so that the `process` method can receive them and *change the UI in the event handling thread*. Modifying the UI (as the call `table.addMarket(market);` suggests) and publishing just integer numbers, defeats the entire purpose of this class.